# Why does my input seen to lose it's model binding when I update a collection?

Tags: angular, typescript

So I've created a simple recipe calculator that allows the user to add ingredients to a list, and set the quantities. The list of ingredients is an array, and every time the user clicks 'Add ingredient' it should create a new empty ingredient item where the user can select both the ingredient and the quantity.

This appears to work initially ie. when the app first loads and the user adds an ingredient, they can select the ingredient and set a quantity. But the moment the user adds another ingredient (and another empty item is added to the array), the form seems to lose reference to the model it was bound to.

But when I look at the json output of the model it looks fine? I can't see where I'm going wrong.

Here's an example of me adding the first ingredient:

[image]

You can see the inputs are binding to the correct fields.

However when I add a second item I see the following:

[image]

So you can see the json is correct ie. the first ingredient remains the same, but now a second item is in the array - however the inputs have reset back to their empty value.

This is the component mark-up:

```
<form #recipesForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(recipesForm)" class="qc-panel" *ngIf="showRecipesForm()">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="name" class="form-label">Recipes name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
           required
           [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name"
           #name="ngModel">
    <div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
      Name is required
    </div>
  </div>

  <ul class="mb-3 ingredients-list">
    <li *ngFor="let ingredient of model.ingredients; let i = index; trackBy: trackByIndex" class="ingredients-list__item">
      <select class="form-select qc-input--lg" [(ngModel)]="model.ingredients[i].definition" name="ingredient">
        <option [value]="{}" disabled>Please select</option>
        <option *ngFor="let definition of definitions" [ngValue]="definition" [disabled]="disableOption(definition)">{{ definition.name }}</option>
      </select>

      <div class="input-group qc-input--md" [hidden]="!showQuantity(ingredient)">
        <input type="number" class="form-control"
               [(ngModel)]="model.ingredients[i].quantity" name="quantity" />
        <span class="input-group-text">{{ ingredient.definition.measurement }}</span>
      </div>

      <a [routerLink]="[]" (click)="removeIngredient(model, ingredient)" class="qc-action"><fa-icon [icon]="faTrash"></fa-icon></a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary d-block" [disabled]="disableAdd()" (click)="addIngredient()">Add ingredient</button>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary d-block mt-5" [disabled]="disableSave()">Save recipe</button>

  <div [hidden]="!showRecipeExists || recipesForm.pristine" class="alert alert-danger mb-3">
    A recipe already exists with this name
  </div>

</form>
```

As you can see, the model for the inputs is the item in the array at the specified index.. and that seems to work for the initial ingredient. But anything after that breaks.

Here is the back-end of the component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

import { faTrash } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { Definition } from '../definition';
import { DefinitionService } from '../definition.service';
import { Ingredient } from '../ingredient';
import { Recipe } from '../recipe';
import { RecipeService } from '../recipe.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipes',
  templateUrl: './recipes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipes.component.scss', '../../assets/sass/shared.scss']
})
export class RecipesComponent {
  definitions: Definition[] = [];
  recipes: Recipe[] = [];

  constructor(private definitionService: DefinitionService, private recipeService: RecipeService) { }

  // Icons
  faTrash = faTrash;

  model: Recipe = {
    name: '',
    ingredients: [] as Ingredient[]
  };

  showRecipeExists = false;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getDefinitions();
    this.getRecipes();
  }

  showRecipesForm(): boolean {
    return this.definitions.length > 0;
  }

  showRecipesTable(): boolean {
    return this.recipes.length > 0;
  }

  disableAdd(): boolean {
    if (this.definitions.length === this.model.ingredients.length)
      return true;

    if (this.model.ingredients.length > 0) {
      let count = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.model.ingredients.length; i++) {
        if (Object.keys(this.model.ingredients[i].definition).length === 0)
          count++;
      }

      if (count !== 0)
        return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  disableSave(): boolean {
    if (this.model.ingredients.length === 0)
      return true;

    let ingredientNotSet = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.model.ingredients.length; i++) {
      if (Object.keys(this.model.ingredients[i].definition).length === 0)
        return true;
    }

    if (ingredientNotSet)
      return true;

    return false;
  }

  disableOption(definition: Definition): boolean {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.model.ingredients.length; i++) {
      if (this.model.ingredients[i].definition.name === definition.name)
        return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  showQuantity(ingredient: Ingredient): boolean {
    if (Object.keys(ingredient.definition).length !== 0)
      return true;

    return false;
  }

  addIngredient(): void {
    let ingredient: Ingredient = {
      quantity: 0,
      definition: {} as Definition
    }
    this.model.ingredients.push(ingredient);
  }

  removeIngredient(recipe: Recipe, ingredient: Ingredient): void {
    // Remove the ingredient from the array
    for (let i = recipe.ingredients.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (Object.keys(ingredient.definition).length === 0 || recipe.ingredients[i].definition.name === ingredient.definition.name) {
        recipe.ingredients.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
  }

  getDefinitions(): void {
    this.definitionService.getDefinitions()
      .subscribe(definitions => {
        this.definitions = definitions
      });
  }

  getRecipes(): void {
    this.recipeService.getRecipes()
      .subscribe(recipes => {
        this.recipes = recipes
      });
  }

  trackByIndex(index: number, obj: any): any {
    return index;
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm): void {

    if (this.recipeService.existsWithName(form.value as Recipe)) {
      this.showRecipeExists = true;
      return;
    }

    this.recipeService.addRecipe(form.value as Recipe)
      .subscribe(recipe => {
        this.recipes.push(recipe);
      });

    form.resetForm({
      name: '',
      ingredients: [] as Ingredient[]
    });

    this.getRecipes();
  }

  clearRecipes(): void {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to clear all recipes?')) {
      this.recipeService.clearRecipes();
      this.getRecipes();
    }
  }

  removeDefinition(definition: Definition) {
    this.definitionService.removeDefinition(definition);
    this.getDefinitions();
  }

  removeRecipe(recipe: Recipe) {
    this.recipeService.removeRecipe(recipe);
    this.getRecipes();
  }
}
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not have controls with same names in form, but you have `name="ingredient"`  and `name="quantity"` inside `ngFor`.

You can try `[name]="'ingredient' + i"` and `[name]="'quantity' + i"`

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right! I just read the docs and realised that using the same name for the controls is breaking the form's ability to track the data

Answer (score 1):

I could see there are 3 things missing.

1. Cannot use same name for multiple formControls
2. RecipeForm initialization not found
3. If you add new recipe to DOM, you must add a new formControl with same formControlName as in the DOM.

Make sure to have a balance between DOM (HTML) formControls along with TS formControls.

If you do these, I hope it will resolve the issue.